# Why does my $.getJSON work but not execute the onsuccess part?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, getjson

I have this Javascript:

```
var signUp = {
    share: function(response) {
        alert('hello');
    }
}

$.getJSON("http://pgthatworks.com/?callback=?", {email:signUp.email, api:signUp.api, ref:signUp.ref}, function(response){
signUp.share(response);
});
```

The `$.getJSON()` works up to the point where it is sending the data to the page specified and that page is doing it's job, but the `function(response){}` part does not execute. Any idea why?

Comment: try look into network tab in chrome, and check if you actually get response, or error

Comment: @vittore I am just seeing a GET request

Comment: did you try logging the data that is returned by your server? Maybe you missed something somewhere

Comment: Use the full `ajax` request and let us know what error you receive on callback - http://jsfiddle.net/cRgxZ/

Comment: @JibiAbraham Yes - this is an example JSON returned `["http:\/\/pgthatworks.com\/?ref=rbpxM",1]` - should there be a problem with that?

Comment: @mrtsherman ah... just did it- got `parsererror`

Comment: That parses fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are performing a cross domain request. I say this because you have the full URL specified in your getJSON request along with a callback parameter in the query string. If this is the case, then your PHP needs to send back proper JSONP. That is:

```
print $callbackString.'('.json_encode($your_array).')';
```

Comment: I am doing JSONP so that makes total sense, but what would the `$callbackString` be? I tried `http://pgthatworks.com/?callback=?` but that still returns `parsererror`

Comment: $callbackString is the value of the query parameter as set by jQuery. E.g. $callbackString = $_REQUEST['callback']